# Get number of parameter before call a function in a class

Tags: php, function, class

i am trying to call a function in a class using this line of code..

```
$controller = new $controller;    
$method = 'first';
call_user_func_array([$controller,$method],$params);
```

the problem is not every function have a parameter. but when the $params method is available and the called function is not having any parameters.

and i want to have an action when th

so my question is, how to get a number of parameter on a function before a caling a function in a class?

sory for my bad english, i hope you got the point..
thanks..

Comment: Your example code is a total mess, but in any case `call_user_func_array` was designed to not count the parameters but pass them _as array_.

Answer (score 2):

You can use reflection to look at the function,

https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionfunction.php

There's an example of how to use it in there. To expand on this a little more, you're calling a class method. You can get the class first and then get to the method that way, https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionclass.php